# Can't define method of a class as a friend of another class

Tags: c++, friend, access-control

I'm trying to make MainScheduler's method addJob a friend function of the class Job, as so:

```
#include "MainScheduler.h"
//forward declaration
class MainScheduler;

class Job:
{
    friend void MainScheduler::addJob( Job* const job );
    ...
}
```

But I keep getting the error

> error C2027: use of undefined type 'MainScheduler'

Do you know why am I getting this message, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you have a forward declaration for `MainScheduler` if you've already included `MainScheduler.h`?

Comment: It didn't work before I wrote the forward declaration, with the following error: "error C2653: 'MainScheduler' : is not a class or namespace name". From what I've read in other peoples' questions about similar problems, adding a forward declaration solves the problem. So I thought that I should add a forward declaration. Only at my case, it just changed the error type.

Comment: The forward declaration is just masking the issue.  The forward declaration doesn't tell the compiler that MainScheduler has a method called addJob, for example.  There is probably a problem in MainScheduler.h

Comment: So, why the problem happened when I didn't have the forward declaration? In MainScheduler.h I have the method void addJob(Job* const job);. I don't see what can be the problem in MainScheduler.h.

Comment: Do the two header files use different include guards?  Does MainScheduler.h also try to include Job.h?

Comment: I had a problem of infinite inclusion, see second answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is quite simple: you cannot have dependency cycles.

```
// MainScheduler.h
#ifndef MAINSCHEDULER
#define MAINSCHEDULER

#include "Job.h"

class MainScheduler { friend class Job; };

#endif


// Job.h
#ifndef JOB
#define JOB

#include "MainScheduler.h"

class Job { friend class MainScheduler; };

#endif
```

What happens here when parsing MainScheduler.h is the following:

- `MAINSCHEDULER` is not defined, thus the parsing starts
- the preprocessor defines `MAINSCHEDULER`
- the preprocessor includes Job.h
- because `MAINSCHEDULER` is already defined, it skips the inclusion of MainScheduler.h
- it includes the tokens from `Job`
- includes of Job.h ends
- it includes the tokens from `MainScheduler`

This yields the following preprocessor output, which the compiler sees:

```
// ignored #include "MainScheduler.h"

class Job { friend class MainScheduler; };

class MainScheduler { friend class Job; };
```

this is why before you introduced the forward declaration the compiler complained about the unknown `MainScheduler` symbol in the definition of `Job`.

Your headers cannot include themselves in a cycle, and you cannot befriend a member function with only a forward declaration.

I propose you rewrite Job.h as:

```
class MainScheduler; // forward declaration

class Job {
    friend class MainScheduler;
public:
    // whatever

};
```

By befriending the whole class you get away with just a forward declaration and break the cycle.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I did such a mistake. Anyway, there is something I don't understand - Why can't I befriend a member function with a forward declaration? (I should really try to avoid the friend class solution, as I am strictly asked to expose as little as possible and encapsulate as much as possible.)

Comment: @Idan: because to be able to befriend a method, this method must be declared. Since the class has not been defined (just forward declared), then its methods are unknown, and cannot be befriended.

Answer (score 5):

You can only name a member function that has already been declared, even for a friendship declaration.  This means the class must be defined, not just forward-declared.

Wrong:

```
class X;

class Y
{
    friend void X::f(); // ERROR
};
```

Right:

```
class X
{
public:
    void f();
};

class Y
{
    friend void X::f();
};
```

It's not obvious why your `#include "MainScheduler.h"` did not make the definition of `class MainScheduler` visible, so something else strange is going on there.

This rule means it is not possible to do something like `A::f()` is a friend of `B` and `B::g()` is a friend of `A`, so sometimes you just have to settle for friending an entire class.  (Or there are fancy ways of using helper classes to request/grant permission for certain sets of functions, but that's more helpful when you need an extensible library interface.)